# Laravel dynamic where queries using Query Builder

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, eloquent

I am in new in Laravel. I want to make dynamic where queries with laravel query builder.
Normally I can make dynamic queries in php

```
$where = array(
  'hello' => 'world'
);

function get($where = null){
   if($where == "")  $where = "";
  //Function which converts where clause into queries
  wheretoqueries($where);  //converts where clause
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl $where";
  return $sql; 
}
echo get($where);
```

If where clause is null queries will be

```
SELECT * FROM $tbl
```

If where clause is not null queries will be

```
SELECT * FROM $tbl WHERE hello = "world"
```

Laravel orm works fine for where clause if key and value exists

```
A::where($where)->get();
```

If where is null following method will not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. If $where variable contain something then the query will execute otherwise it will retrieve all data from `A` Model.

```
 function get($where = null){
     if($where != null){
        A::where('field_name', '=', $where)->first(); 
     }else{
        A::all();
     }
  }
```

**Note:** if your query return more than one value then you have to use get() method at end of query builder instead of first();
Reference: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#where-clauses

Comment: Happy to know that my answer is helpful.

Answer (score 9):

You can chain the [`where`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#retrieving-results) queries as:

```
$query = Model::query();

if (!empty($value)) {
   $query->where('column', $value);
}

$query->get();
```

OR

You can use [`when`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#conditional-clauses) method as:

```
Model::when($value, function ($query) use ($value) {
        return $query->where('column', $value);
    })
    ->get();
```

Comment: By using this method you can add chaining on the query.